# Node/React: Serve static json file

Tags: node.js, json, reactjs, express, nginx

On my website I have some categories in the database which don't change often. I am using the NextJS framework. In order to decrease the load time and make category control load faster I am thinking of putting categories in a json file under `/static/data/categories.json` and let React fetch that json file instead of making a database call. I have read about multiple approaches to importing static json files including `json-loader`. However, I am thinking of making an api call something like the following from React once on the home page and store the contents in redux state so that I could use them wherever I need. My intention here is whenever categories are modified, I update categories.json and the client will fetch the updated json file. Deployment downtime is not an issue for me.

```js
const categories = yield call(request, `${BASE_URL}/static/data/categories.json`, options);
```

My questions are:

1. Is this a right approach to load a json file from the server keeping in mind I would want to update the file every few months without the need to redeploy the whole website.
2. Can a json file become a bottleneck if thousands of concurrent users try to access it. I am using express with nginx. Would using `express.static` help at all?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the data is static and every client needs it, why wouldn't you just embed it in the web page (dynamically inserted) and save the extra http request from every client to initially fetch it.  You can still allow a client to get an update via http, but they won't have to use that first http request when they load your page.

Comment: There should be no issue with hundreds of client requesting a static file.  It's definitely good to get this load off the database.

Comment: @jfriend00 It is a valid point. However, I have noticed when I import the json file in React using `import categories from 'categories.json' it gets cached in the browser and require a hard reload which is not ideal in my case.

Comment: If you don't want the browser to cache the file, you can control that on the server.

Comment: @jfriend00 I have updated the question. How about thousands of concurrent users try to access the file. Should there still be no issue?

Comment: That's too generic a question without any metrics to evaluate the load.  Express is good at serving static files.  If you have thousands of users, you already need to be serving other resources to all those users (web pages, images, scripts, etc...), I'm not sure why you're so concerned about one additional resource per user. Do you put that much thought into how many script files or how many images your pages have?  A static JSON file is no different than any one of those other resources.

Comment: Plus, if you wanted to reduce the load on Express, you could change any of your static resources so they are served by NGINX instead which it is very optimized for.

Comment: @jfriend00 Very good point about NGNIX. I read about it just last night. I will consider that in future. Appreciate your help!